# Kubernetes's Ingress annotations for x509 certificate authentificate

Tags: kubernetes, annotations

I'm trying to use kubernetes ingress annotation rules in order to enable X509 authentication.
My ingress yaml file is defined below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: bdf-opengie-test
  name: keycloak-opengie-test-ssl
  labels:
    app: keycloak-opengie
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "opengie-tls-secret"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "3"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: keycloak-opengie-test-ssl.bdf-clu4.paas.eclair.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: keycloak-opengie
          servicePort: http
  tls:
   - hosts:
     - keycloak-opengie-test-ssl.bdf-clu4.paas.eclair.local
```

When I invoke my application url, I'm expecting to see a popup requesting for a certificate, but nothing happens.
It seems like the annotations has no effect in the ingress definition. 
Can someone tell me what's going wrong in my ingress definition.
I'm using Nginx Ingress: 0.15.0 and Kubernetes 1.10.5

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are missing the secret with SSL files issued for your domain. (if we are talking about a native k8s secret management) You secret should be created by:

```
kubectl --namespace bdf-opengie-test create secret tls <secret_name> --key <key_path> --cert <cert_path>
```

Then your `Ingress` .yml file should contain this secret:

```
 ...
 tls:
   - hosts:
     - keycloak-opengie-test-ssl.<domain>
     secretName: <secret_name>
```

Only after this you can think about any annotations for auth or something else which is not working

Note: the secret is a namespaced object.

Answer (score 0):

```
ingress:
    hostname: id.login.example.com
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: "more_clear_input_headers \"x-forwarded-client-cert\";\n  more_set_input_headers \"x-forwarded-client-cert: $ssl_client_cert\";\n"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/truststore-development.crt;
        ssl_verify_depth 2;
        ssl_session_cache off;
```